# Can't change card header colour with Google Card Service

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to change the colours of a Google Workspace Add-on. In the manifest, I specify the primary and secondary colours, but when I run the add-on, only the secondary colour is applied.

Here's the full manifest. The colours where copied from a tutorial. With these settings, the header should be green, but it remains dark grey. The text buttons are properly displayed (purple instead of the generic blue).

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "myApp",
      "logoUrl": "https://i.postimg.cc/logo.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#41f470",
        "secondaryColor": "#ab2699"
      },
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onhomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "forms": {},
    "sheets": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to completely close the document in which I as trying the add-on. Reloading the add-on is enough to try changes in the functionalities, but not to check changes to the header.

It is so basic that I wonder if I should simply delete the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).